# Interactive C program with shell key mapping?

Tags: c, shell, emacs

I want to write a interactive program in C just like shell, but I do not need to execute external
program. I want to add a feature like emacs-style key binding, history. e.g. enter <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> will show 
previous typed command. Is there any way to add such a feature?

Comment: Is [Readline](http://www.gnu.org/software/readline/‎) what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks,it seems like a good starting point

Comment: To quickly get this kind of feature without any development effort, you can use external wrappers such as [rlwrap](http://utopia.knoware.nl/~hlub/rlwrap/#rlwrap), as in `rlwrap myprogram my_args`. It doesn't offer the tight command-line integration that readline does, but is still a good starting point to provide your users with a subset of readline's features while you develop the full thing.